# How to remove blur from UITextField keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that shows a list of countries, and I want the `PickerView` to have no background at all, also no blur effect, I managed to remove the color using this line of code:

```
picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

yet, I could not remove the blur effect. Is it possible to remove it?

UPDATE:

I have just realized that the blur effect comes from the `UITextField` and not from `UIPickerView`, but still can not find a way around it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188042/blur-effect-background-uitextfield ?

Comment: @CarstenHagemann Not really, I am asking about removing the blur effect from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick that works, instead of trying to remove the blur from the keyboard I changed the background color of the `UIPickerView` to match the `UIView` background color using this line inside the `numberOfRowsInComponent` function:

```
picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

And if you are using a gradient color for your `UIView` background you can use this line:

```
picker.addGradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor.black, secondColor: UIColor.white)
```

But you have to manage the colors correctly to get the best results.

Also if you only have the hex values of the colors you can convert them to `UIColor` easily using [this site](http://uicolor.xyz/#/hex-to-ui)

Additional note:

In my case, I was using a gradient color for my `UIView` background, and a function that moves `UITextField` when keyboard is presented which you can find [here](http://www.seemuapps.com/move-uitextfield-when-keyboard-is-presented), thankfully this made it much easier, since I only needed to use only one color for the `UIPickerView` background which is the color at the bottom-most of the `UIView` background.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and found one solution for hidden blur view bellow my custom inputView.
You can addObserver the notification of keyboard will show, and hidden the blur view.
I also tested iOS 9 -> 12. 
Hope this can help.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil
    )

@objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let superView = inputView?.superview else { return }
    for childView in superView.subviews where childView != inputView {
        childView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Result:
[Simulator 5s on iOS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejlP0.png)